# Convert column with YYYY-MM-DD to week number

Tags: r, date, week-number

I am trying to get the week number from my EventDate column which has YYYY-MM-DD data, at the moment I am writing SQL in R but if anyone has any idea how to write R code only would be great too.

I have tried Datepart but it didn't work.

e.g :

```
EventDate     WeekNumber 
2020-02-03      ?
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `week` function from `lubridate`:

```r
library(lubridate)
some_dates <- ymd(c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-07", "2020-01-08", "2020-12-29", "2020-12-31"))
week(some_dates)
#> [1]  1  1  2 52 53
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```r
> strftime("2020-02-03", format = "%V")
[1] "06"

> strftime(c("2014-03-16", "2014-03-17","2014-03-18", "2014-01-01"), format = "%V") 
[1] "11" "12" "12" "01"
```